# require.context: inline RegExp works, var RegExp does not

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I am trying to load my tests conditionally if the SPEC Env is declared:

```
var context = null
if (process.env.SPEC) {
  context = require.context('./tests', true, /.*?SearchInput.*/);
} 
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

This is perfectly working.
Now If I do this

```
var context = null
if (process.env.SPEC) {
  var c = /.*?SearchInput.*/;
  context = require.context('./tests', true, c);
} 
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

This is not working at all and all files in ./ are matched (the './tests' parameter get ignored)

What am I missing? 
I want the third parameter of the require.context function to be a RegExp object so I can construct the RegExp using a variable.

**EDIT 1**

This does not work:

```
var context = null
if (process.env.SPEC) {
  var c = new RegExp(/.*?SearchInput.*/);
  context = require.context('./tests', true, c);
} 
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

To test this you can edit the tests.webpack.js file of this project:
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

You need to allow the SPEC variable to pass through webpack

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('test'),
        SPEC: JSON.stringify(process.env.SPEC || null)
      },
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: false  // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
    })
```

and run: npm run test

or: SPEC=t npm run test

Comment: Have you tried using the `RegExp` constructor?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @nnnnnn No idea. It should work fine with the literal assigned to the variable, but according to OP it doesn't. Trying with the constructor would provide an additional data point and might help in identifying the cause.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes I tried the RegExp constructor but it does not work. I edited the question.

Comment: `var c = new RegExp(/.*?SearchInput.*/);` should be `var c = new RegExp('.*?SearchInput.*');` because the `RegExp` constructor accepts a `string`, not a regex literal.

Comment: ```var c = new RegExp('.*?SearchInput.*');
  context = require.context('./tests', true, c);``` does not work neither.

Answer (score 3):

Sokra answered this on the webpack github saying that the regexp passed to require.context must be statically analyzable. That's why passing `/thing/` works but not `new RegExp(thing)`

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772

Answer (score 2):

4 years later, facing the same issue. Check the warning message for `require.context`

https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext